# How to avoid losing selection with Helm

Tags: helm, region

Whenever I select a region and execute an extended command (`M-x`), `Helm` opens and I immediately lose the ring selection highlighting. Is there a way of stopping `Helm` from doing so?

My `Helm` configuration (which I adapted from [here](http://pages.sachachua.com/.emacs.d/Sacha.html)) is this:

```
(use-package helm
  :init
  (progn 
    (require 'helm-config) 
    (setq helm-candidate-number-limit 10)
    ;; From https://gist.github.com/antifuchs/9238468
    (setq helm-idle-delay 0.0 ; update fast sources immediately (doesn't).
          helm-input-idle-delay 0.01  ; this actually updates things
                                        ; reeeelatively quickly.
          helm-quick-update t
          helm-M-x-requires-pattern nil
          helm-split-window-in-side-p t
          helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching t
          helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source t
          helm-ff-search-library-in-sexp t
          helm-ff-file-name-history-use-recentf t
          helm-ff-skip-boring-files t)
    (helm-mode))
  :config
  (progn
    ;; I don't like the way switch-to-buffer uses history, since
    ;; that confuses me when it comes to buffers I've already
    ;; killed. Let's use ido instead.
    (add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(switch-to-buffer . ido)))
  :bind (("C-c h" . helm-mini)))
(ido-mode -1) ;; Turn off ido mode in case I enabled it accidentally
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update Helm again, to at least version 20141105.654. It was fixed after the [issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/690) was reported.